# Loading and executing scripts after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, cross-domain

I am trying to load an external javascript (jquery) via my Firefox addon to a third-party webpage, WebDeveloper addons shows the jquery script syntax getting successfully appended to the head section in "View Generated Source" but the script is not getting executed/fetched ?, I am using the following code in my addon to load the script :

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
  fileref.setAttribute('onload', 'firefoxInit()');

}
else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
}
if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Pls. guide how to move forward.

Comment: You're not gonna get access to `fileref` in the last `if` statement, as it's declared in the first `if-else` scope.. But doubt that's the answer you're looking for ;)

Comment: favor direct property assignment over set attribute, buggy in some browser, use fileref.src instead

Comment: @freaktm - strangely the script is still getting appended to DOM ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add at the end of your javascript `firefoxInit();` and remove the `onload` attribute assignment.

Comment: Thanks Mic, I am starting with javascript and that gave error : "firefoxInit is not defined"

Comment: I thought `firefoxInit` was defined in this JS file, but may be it isn't. If you call a function at the end of the JS file, you can be sure, that everything before is loaded. And in this function call you can run the command to start the logic.